# Clone elements found with different selectors, avoiding code repetition

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, simplify

Could you please help me, how to simplify this code? I think, it is too long and confused.

```
var launchPad = $(".launchPad").clone();
var launchPad_plankovy = $(".launchPad-plankovy").clone();
var launchPad_plankovy_tvarovany = $(".launchPad-plankovy-tvarovany").clone();
var launchPad_tyckovy = $(".launchPad-tyckovy").clone();
var launchPad_kombinovany = $(".launchPad-kombinovany").clone();
var launchPad_barvy_plankovy = $(".launchPad-barvy-plankovy").clone();
var launchPad_barvy_tyckovy = $(".launchPad-barvy-tyckovy").clone();
var launchPad_zakonceni_plotovek = $(".launchPad-zakonceni-plotovek").clone();
var launchPad_zakonceni_tycek = $(".launchPad-zakonceni-tycek").clone();

$("[name='reset']").click(function(){
  $(".launchPad").html(launchPad.html());
  $(".launchPad-plankovy").html(launchPad_plankovy.html());
  $(".launchPad-plankovy-tvarovany").html(launchPad_plankovy_tvarovany.html());
  $(".launchPad-tyckovy").html(launchPad_tyckovy.html());
  $(".launchPad-kombinovany").html(launchPad_kombinovany.html());
  $(".launchPad-barvy-plankovy").html(launchPad_barvy_plankovy.html());
  $(".launchPad-barvy-tyckovy").html(launchPad_barvy_tyckovy.html());
  $(".launchPad-zakonceni-plotovek").html(launchPad_zakonceni_plotovek.html());
  $(".launchPad-zakonceni-tycek").html(launchPad_zakonceni_tycek.html());
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make [one big selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and collect all elements at once. You can apply `clone` on all of them in one call. For restoring, you would reuse that same selector, loop over the results and replace the HTML from the collected clones.

```
var $restorable = $(".launchPad, .launchPad-plankovy, " +
    " .launchPad-plankovy-tvarovany, .launchPad-tyckovy, .launchPad-kombinovany, " +
    " .launchPad-barvy-plankovy, .launchPad-barvy-tyckovy, " +
    " .launchPad-zakonceni-plotovek, .launchPad-zakonceni-tycek");

var $launchPad = $restorable.clone();

$("[name='reset']").click(function (){
    $restorable.each(function (i) {
        $(this).html($launchPad.eq(i).html());
    });
});
```

I do seem to notice you give unique classes to each of your elements. It is better to use `id` properties for that purpose, and use classes for marking the same kind of elements with the same class. If you would use one class for all these elements, like `'restorable'`, the list would not have to be that long.

Also, as you only use the HTML of the clones, you will get better performance and memory usage, if you don't actually clone, but just save the HTML. Together with the idea to give the class `restorable` to all these elements, the code becomes:

```
var $restorable = $(".restorable");

var launchPadHtml = $restorable.map(function() { return $(this).html(); }).get();

$("[name='reset']").click(function (){
    $restorable.each(function (i) {
        $(this).html(launchPadHtml[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var keys = ['launchPad-plankovy-tvarovany', 'launchPad-plankovy' ...];
var clones = {};
keys.forEach(function(key){
  clones[key] = $('.' + key).clone();
}

$("[name='reset']").click(function(){
  keys.forEach(function(key){
    $('.' + key).html(clones[key];
  }
});
```

In lodash, it's move elegant:

```
var keys = ['launchPad-plankovy-tvarovany', 'launchPad-plankovy' ...];
var clones = _.zipObject(keys, _.map(keys, function(key){
  return $('.' + key).clone();
});
```